# What should be the approach to show coupons?

Tags: forms, marketing, discount

We have a system where user can see all the coupons from his account which can be used by him. This number can range from 0 to 8 coupons. The no of coupons are exposed to user 2-3 places in the system through dashboard, dedicated pages and other. While user gets into form for placing an order, at last stage we want to show those coupon(s) in order to apply.

**Now the real problem:**
While user gets into form for placing an order, at last stage we want to show those coupon(s) in order to apply.

- User should be allowed to use multiple coupons at a time for single or multiple products.
- Coupons are product specific, hence only relevant coupon(s) can be applied, other will be not applicable depending on which product(s) user has chosen.
- User can select multiple products [and hence multiple relevant coupon(s)]

There are two approaches to show coupon(s):

1. **Show all coupons** which are in his account. based on products selected, make them enabled or disabled. For disabled coupons, have a message that those are disabled as those are not applicable to the products selected.
2. **Show only relevant coupons** for the selected products. In this case, as there might be multiple products, there might be multiple coupons. Few of them would apply to one but not other and vice-a-versa. So even in this case coupons should be shown with applicable to XYZ product and not applicable to PQR product needs to be shown upfront.

Team is debating which approach to go for. I am in favour of approach 1 cos if we don't show all coupons, users will deviate from placing order and go to coupons details page to copy code and paste in manual coupon code text box (yes we do provide that also). And everything will be in-vain when he will come to know that the coupon is not applicable to the product selected. Then why not show upfront even that is negative (saying not applicable to product selected)

Any suggestion which approach to go with? with any rationale?

**Note:** The products are not any general products so that user will go around googling for coupon codes. These are very specific and have chances of getting coupons internally only. We don't anticipate user googling for coupons for these products.

**btw,** I am least worried about the UI/layout, cos the UI I have created, works for both these approaches. I am concerned more with users expectancy for seeing coupons (logically)

Answer (score 2):

When showing multiple offers, then an emphasized product suggestion might be a good idea as some people need a little nudge. I believe there are some psychology studies out there which suggest that the more choice there is, then the lower the chances of a decision actually being made and acted upon. In order to combat such analysis paralysis, try emphasizing and highlighting certain options above others.[image]

Comment: Good point but with all respect, this does not solve my problem. It's not about selling other products, its about which coupons to be shown (logically). I am least worried about the UI/layout cos the UI I created, works for both of these approaches I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Coupons can be a reward for participating with you and your site, as an interactive game of sorts, rather than a discount that's automatically applied. Another sort of coupon is given to customers for their aggregate purchases. This second flavor of coupon may or may not have an expiration date. The more respect a coupon bears, the more appropriate it seems to give it a spotlight. I thought I might show one way in which coupons can encourage customers to increase their order.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with option 1 show all coupons.  But why show at very end only?  This is risky.  If show at very end more likely they will defect to add other products.  I would say create a left rail and make it visible earlier in process.  Next to the coupons for the other products maybe you can have either a quick auto add or link to that product page opens in new tab